# How to remove the close(x) option from excel userform?

Tags: excel, vba

How to remove the close( X ) option from excel userform ? I got the below link which already discussed.
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/694008-remove-user-form-borders.html

But i'm getting what they given, please help me....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly: make sure you include at least one obvious method to close the form!!

Instead of bothering the end user with message box's after they click close, I would hide the close altogether:

```
'//Find the userform's Window
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
        Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

'//Get the current window style
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
        Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

'//Set the new window style
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
        Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long, _
        ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Const WS_SYSMENU = &H80000

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Dim hWnd As Long, lStyle As Long

   If Val(Application.Version) >= 9 Then
      hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)
   Else
      hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", Me.Caption)
   End If

   '//Get the current window style and turn off the Close button
   lStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE)
   SetWindowLong hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (lStyle And Not WS_SYSMENU)
End Sub
```

If you want to prevent closing via ALT-F4 then use this as well:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
      If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True  
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to add that even with the close button hidden, the user can still close the window with Alt+F4

Comment: + 1 :) Yup API is the only way to hide the close button.

Comment: I needed to add a Call DrawMenuBar(HWnd) and its declaration. Also the declarations will not work with Office 64, see jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp.

Comment: Needed to call DrawMenuBar() because I changed the menu bar **after** the userform was initialized!