# Hide close [X] button on excel vba userform for my progress bar

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I created a userform to show a progress bar when the macro is still importing sheets
[image]

The problem is the user can press the red **[X]** button that will close and interrupt the processing done.

Is there a way to hide this *red button of doom* so that potential users don't have any confusing buttons to click while it runs.

edit:

I have tried this

```
'Find the userform's Window
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
        Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

'Get the current window style
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
        Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

'Set the new window style
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
        Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long, _
        ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Const WS_SYSMENU = &H80000
```

and I used this on userform_initialize

```
   Dim hWnd As Long, lStyle As Long

   'Which type of userform
   If Val(Application.Version) >= 9 Then
      hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)
   Else
      hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", Me.Caption)
   End If

   'Get the current window style and turn off the Close button
   lStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE)
   SetWindowLong hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (lStyle And Not WS_SYSMENU)
```

I am getting this error message
[image]

this code was taken from [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/7312-get-rid-close-button-form.html#post106883). I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I already removed the comments. This is the simplest code that I found so I would like to integrate it to my userform. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer to this question came up as my top search result. Did you try anything?

Comment: updated with some more info

Comment: Could you clarify and change the word 'disable' to 'hide and disable' if this is what you intend to do? Disabling the functionality is relatively simple. Hiding it appears to not be.

Comment: @forums: Did you try the code below?

Comment: To fix the problem you show in the screenshot: move all the API declaration to the top of the module!

Comment: @PeterAlbert, a friend also noticed that this morning so it was just fixed thanks. Did not know that you cannot just place a block of code anywhere in VBA. I only thought `Options` should be at the top.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the close(x) option from excel userform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150186/how-to-remove-the-closex-option-from-excel-userform)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Below is a routine that you can call like this:

```
subRemoveCloseButton MyForm
```

or from within your form:

```
subRemoveCloseButton Me
```

Here's the code you'll need:

```
Private Const mcGWL_STYLE = (-16)
Private Const mcWS_SYSMENU = &H80000

'Windows API calls to handle windows
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
#End If


Public Sub subRemoveCloseButton(frm As Object)
    Dim lngStyle As Long
    Dim lngHWnd As Long

    lngHWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    lngStyle = GetWindowLong(lngHWnd, mcGWL_STYLE)

    If lngStyle And mcWS_SYSMENU > 0 Then
        SetWindowLong lngHWnd, mcGWL_STYLE, (lngStyle And Not mcWS_SYSMENU)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I needed to add a `Call DrawMenuBar(HWnd)` and its declaration. Also the declarations are messed up and will not work with Office 64, see http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp.

Comment: @amadeus: what do you need the DrawMenuBar for? And which declaration is messed up? (I don't have a 64bit Excel at hand to test...) thanks!

Comment: If you call subRemoveCloseButton() when the form is already rendered (i.e. not from within Userform_Initialize()), then the Menu does not change. In that case you have to call DrawMenuBar() to rerender. As for the 64bit support, all Long values representing pointers must be replaced by LongPtr. For example FindWindow() does return a LongPtr, not a Long. Same for the hwnd parameters.

Comment: ATTENTION: With this call of `FindWindow(vbNullString, frm.Caption)` it may happen, that if your UserForm has the same caption as any other program's window, that its [x] button is being removed instead of the UserForm's [x] button. I posted an improved function below binding `FindWindow` to UserForms and including x64 safe API calls.

Answer (score 10):

You can work it out from the following snippets:

Select the `cmdClose` button
On the Menu bar, choose `View | Code`
Where the cursor is flashing, enter the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

On the Menu bar, choose `View | Object`, to return to the UserForm.

**To allow users to close the form by pressing the Esc key:**

Select the cmdClose button
In the Properties window, change the `Cancel` property to `True`

**To prevent users from closing the form by clicking the X button**

When the `UserForm` is opened, there is an `X` at the top right. In addition to using the Close Form button, people will be able to close the form by using the X. If you want to prevent that, follow these steps.

Right-click on an empty part of the UserForm
Choose `View | Code`
From the Procedure dropdown, at the top right, choose QueryClose

Where the cursor is flashing, paste the highlighted code from the following sample

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, _
  CloseMode As Integer)
  If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Please use the Close Form button!"
  End If
End Sub
```

On the Menu bar, choose `View | Object`, to return to the UserForm.
Now, if someone clicks the `X` in the UserForm, they'll see your message.

from http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html

Comment: What I need is the close button to disappear completely. Its a common answer when I googled it, but I need a way to hide the [X] mark.

Comment: Hiding the button is purely aesthetic. Altho this answer doesn't hide the button, it disables it, and is the easiest to implement (no API stuff). This is my favorite solution. But, the "Don't click here!" message box is overengineering. The minimum coding needed in the `UserForm_QueryClose` procedure is simply `Cancel = True`.

Comment: Correction to my comment above: the minimum code is `If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True`. Answer would be better if you explain CloseMode.

Answer (score 7):

### This is an improvement of the above answer of @Peter Albert

- Windows API calls are now Office x64 safe
- `FindWindow` call was improved to find Excel UserForms only. The function in the original answer searches every window class (e.g. Explorer windows and other program's windows). Therefore it could happen that the [x] button of other programs or explorer windows have been removed when their name was the same name as the UserForm.

---

```
Private Const mcGWL_STYLE = (-16)
Private Const mcWS_SYSMENU = &H80000

'Windows API calls to handle windows
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
  
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongPtrA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#End If

Public Sub RemoveCloseButton(objForm As Object)
    Dim lngStyle As LongPtr
    Dim lngHWnd As LongPtr
    
    Dim lpClassName As String
    lpClassName = vbNullString
    If Val(Application.Version) >= 9 Then
       lpClassName = "ThunderDFrame"
    Else
       lpClassName = "ThunderXFrame"
    End If
    
    lngHWnd = FindWindow(lpClassName, objForm.Caption)
    lngStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(lngHWnd, mcGWL_STYLE)

    If lngStyle And mcWS_SYSMENU > 0 Then
        SetWindowLongPtr lngHWnd, mcGWL_STYLE, (lngStyle And Not mcWS_SYSMENU)
    End If
End Sub
```

> **ThunderDFrame?**
> The UserForms in Excel are actually of the Windows class `ThunderDFrame`, which is the class for all UserFroms in Microsoft Office applications after 2002. Before that, it was `ThunderXFrame`.

Comment: Slightly late but thank you for the update.

Answer (score 4):

A useful way to disable the button is to do the following:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Although this doesn't *get rid* of the button, but it does make clicking on it accomplish nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the user if they want to close the form - and lose edits (say).
Based on ideas from Justin & Peter.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, _
                            CloseMode As Integer)
Dim ans
If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    ans = Msgbox("Cancel edit?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    If ans = vbYes Then
       Me.Hide
    End if
End If
End Sub
```

Edit: Actually I realise this is a bit off topic as OP wanted to remove the X option - but still I find this handy for interactive forms.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but for the type of user form the OP cited, you don't have to remove, hide or disable the close button. There is a much simpler way ;)

For any user form which does not have any elements which the user interacts with (buttons etc) and which will close itself when it has finished its purpose, simply disabling the form is fine.

**To disable the user form:
In the user form's properties, against Enabled set False. The user form will show until it's code tells it to hide. The user will not be able to do anything to the form (cannot close, cannot move etc).**

Note also that whether you want the user to be able to do anything else in the main window while the user form is still showing decides whether you set ShowModal.