# How to show message box until calculations are done?

Tags: excel, vba

I want place this macro to autoopen and wait until finished to avoid user abort calculations.

This is macro that I found and seems to do what I want. But I want to show msxbog to display "Please wait until calculations are finished" and after its done, then close it. Any idea how I can do it?

```
Sub WaitUntilFinishedLoop()

    'Loop until all your calculations are done
    Application.Calculate 'Optional - recalculates all formulas
    Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
        ' Show msgbox / dialog?
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your sub showing the userform `vbModal`

```
Sub WaitUntilFinishedLoop()
    Userform1.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

And make your userform performing the calculation and close it.

```
Public CalcWasStarted As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If CalcWasStarted Then Exit Sub 'make sure it can only run once
    CalcWasStarted = True

    'RemoveCloseButton Me 'see [1]

    'Loop until all your calculations are done
    Application.Calculate 'Optional - recalculates all formulas
    Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

[1] You might want to use what I [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40286183/3219613) to hide the  `[X]` in the userform to prevent that a user can close the form before calculation is finished.

If you want to prevent it from closing with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> add the following to your userform code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't prevent ALT+F4

Comment: @Andreas now it does.

Comment: And now you have created a workbook that is outside of the users control in case something goes wrong. The one thing I do not like. YMMV, but I like to be in control. If a user does not understand a simple message "Please wait for calculations to be done" then wrap their chair in electric cattle fence instead and control that from VBA.

Comment: Well, that was exactly the question: "Box until calculation is done." it will automatically close when calculation is done, if not it will stay. Note that VBA can as always be aborted with `Ctrl + Pause` so you will never end up in a non-responsive Excel (in case you know what you are doing). All other *"smart"* users are trapped in the box and cannot do stupid things like: "Oh I know this box and can click it away, I can continue working anyway." • If you really think you can create a scenario where you get stuck in my box, then please try, I take that challange ;)

Answer (score -2):

If you create a userform with the information you want then you can just do this:

```
Userform1.Show (0) 
Application.Calculate 'Optional - recalculates all formulas
Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
    doevents
Loop
unload Userform1
```

The user can still close the window but I don't think there is any way to stop a user from having the control, without disabling mouse clicks and such.
And I'm not sure that is such a good idea.

Comment: This cannot work if you show the userform `vbModal`. The code execution will stop  at this line `Userform1.Show (1)` until the userform is closed by the user. Then it will follow with `Application.Calculate`. • You need to change to `Userform1.Show vbModeless` but this then does not prevent the user from proceeding working with the worksheet.

Comment: That was a mistake. It should have been 0

Comment: Have a look at my answer for a solution with `vbModal` and without the user being able to close it.

Comment: Since someone did not read the question clearly enough they downvoted me. There is nothing in the question that says it should limit/hinder the user. Only show a box while the calculations are made. My answer does that.

Comment: Actually reading clearly again the exact wording was *"until calculations are done"* and your box can be made disappear before ^^. Just saying. Btw. it wasn't me down-voting. You know these super smart users exist in every company who realize if they click it away they can continue working without needing to wait 2 min calculation ^^

Comment: Yes, until calculations are done. It does not say anything about preventing does it. My userform appears as the calculations start and disappears when it is done. That suits the question quite nicely in my opinion. Had the question been "I want to prevent my users from ....." then I would agree.

Comment: Well, a matter of interpretation. ^^